# Sum of Two Identically Sized HList's at Compile-Time?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the following attempt at retrieving the recursive sum of two `HList`, shown below:

(Pardon the `Product` in its name for now, please.)

```
package net

import shapeless._
import shapeless.nat._
import shapeless.ops.nat.{Sum, Prod, Mod}

trait SumZippedProduct[L, M] {
  type S
}
object SumZippedProduct {

  type Aux[L, M, O] = SumZippedProduct[L, M] {
    type S = O
  }

  def apply[L <: HList, M <: HList](implicit ev: SumZippedProduct[L, M]) = ev

  // LH - L's head
  // L  - HList
  // MH - M's head
  // M  - HList
  // RS - Recursive Sum (L + H)
  // CS - Current Sum (LH + RH)
  // E  - RS + CS
  implicit def sumZippedInductiveEq5[LH <: Nat, L <: HList, MH <: Nat, M <: HList, RS <: Nat, CS <: Nat, E <: Nat](
    implicit ev: SumZippedProduct.Aux[L, M, RS],
             curr: Sum.Aux[LH, MH, CS],
             total: Sum.Aux[CS, RS, E]
  ): SumZippedProduct[LH :: L, MH :: M] = new SumZippedProduct[LH :: L, MH :: M] {
    type S = E
  }

  implicit val hnils: SumZippedProduct[HNil, HNil] = new SumZippedProduct[HNil, HNil] {
    type S = _0
  }

}
```

When trying it out, it works, I think, for the `HNil` case, but not for a 1-element `HList`:

```
scala> import net.SumZippedProduct
import net.SumZippedProduct

scala> import shapeless._, nat._
import shapeless._
import nat._

// expecting 0 (0 + 0)
scala> SumZippedProduct[HNil, HNil]
res0: net.SumZippedProduct[shapeless.HNil,shapeless.HNil] = net.SumZippedProduct$$anon$2@794b4359

// expecting _4 (1 + 3)
scala> SumZippedProduct[_1 :: HNil, _3 :: HNil]
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: net.SumZippedProduct[shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._1,shapeless.HNil],shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._3,shapeless.HNil]]
       SumZippedProduct[_1 :: HNil, _3 :: HNil]
                       ^
```

Why doesn't it compile when passing `_1 :: HNil` and `_3 :: HNil`?

Also, how can I get the `_0` in `res0`?

```
scala> res0.S
<console>:20: error: value S is not a member of net.SumZippedProduct[shapeless.HNil,shapeless.HNil]
       res0.S
            ^
```

Note - I appreciate if such an implementation already exists in shapeless, but I'm asking this question to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Aux` in the return type of your implicits. Otherwise the concrete type of `S` will get lost.
For the summon method `apply` you also have to use a more precise return type, for the same reason. Since `SumZippedProduct` extends `AnyRef` you can just use `ev.type`; it won't get more precise than that.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import shapeless._
import shapeless.nat._
import shapeless.ops.nat.{Sum, Prod, Mod, ToInt}

trait SumZippedProduct[L, M] {
  type S <: Nat
  final def S(implicit toInt: ToInt[S]): Int = toInt()
}
object SumZippedProduct {

  type Aux[L, M, O] = SumZippedProduct[L, M] {
    type S = O
  }

  def apply[L <: HList, M <: HList](implicit ev: SumZippedProduct[L, M]): ev.type = ev

  implicit def sumZippedInductiveEq5[LH <: Nat, L <: HList, MH <: Nat, M <: HList, RS <: Nat, CS <: Nat, E <: Nat](
    implicit ev: SumZippedProduct.Aux[L, M, RS],
             curr: Sum.Aux[LH, MH, CS],
             total: Sum.Aux[CS, RS, E]
  ): SumZippedProduct.Aux[LH :: L, MH :: M, E] = new SumZippedProduct[LH :: L, MH :: M] {
    type S = E
  }

  implicit val hnils: SumZippedProduct.Aux[HNil, HNil, _0] = new SumZippedProduct[HNil, HNil] {
    type S = _0
  }

}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import shapeless._
import shapeless.nat._
import shapeless.ops.nat.{Sum, Prod, Mod}
defined trait SumZippedProduct
defined object SumZippedProduct

scala> SumZippedProduct[HNil, HNil]
res1: SumZippedProduct.<refinement>.type = SumZippedProduct$$anon$2@673bac03

scala> val a: res1.S = _0
a: res1.S = shapeless._0@4f450e01

scala> SumZippedProduct[_1 :: HNil, _3 :: HNil]
res2: SumZippedProduct.Aux[shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._1,shapeless.HNil],shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._3,shapeless.HNil],this.Out] = SumZippedProduct$$anon$1@2a53bcfa

scala> val a: res2.S = _4
a: res2.S = Succ()

scala> val a: res2.S = _5
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : shapeless.nat._5
    (which expands to)  shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]]
 required: res2.S
    (which expands to)  shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]
       val a: res2.S = _5
                       ^

scala> res2.S
res3: Int = 4
```

I also added a method for generating the corresponding integer value. I actually don't know of an existing way to summon a `Nat` value from a `Nat` type (or maybe I'm just blind...). But I think that in most cases `Nat` is only useful at the type level, and that you'd rather work with actual `Int`s at the value level.

It's also not that hard to implement yourself if you really want value level `Nat`s. But if you look at their implementation in shapeless, they're really just empty boxes, so there's not much you can do with them. Only their types are useful.

Comment: For my own understanding, what is the distinction between `ev.type` and `ev`, per the return type of `SumZippedProduct#apply`?

Comment: It's the singleton type of `ev`, but it is not inferred automatically. So if you don't explicitly say that you want the singleton type as return type `SumZippedProduct[L, M]` will be inferred and you lose type information.

Comment: You could also write is as `def apply[L <: HList, M <: HList](implicit ev: SumZippedProduct[L, M]): SumZippedProduct.Aux[L, M, ev.S] = ev`.